# jackson deserialize nested objects HttpMessageNotReadableException: "Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field ..."

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a model like this:

```
...

private TestClass test;

public TestClass getTest(){
    return test;
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDeserializerTest.class)
public void setTest(TestClass test){
    this.test = test;
}
```

And Here is my `TestClass`:

```
public class TestClass{

      private Integer field1;
      private Integer field2;

       public Integer getField1() {
           return field1;
       }

       public void setField1(Integer field1) {
          this.field1 = field1;
       }

       public Integer getField2() {
          return field2;
       }

       public void setField2(Integer field2) {
          this.field2 = field2;
       }
}
```

And finally here is the `JsonDeserializerTest`:

```
@Component
public class JsonDeserializerTest extends JsonDeserializer<TestClass> {


    @Override
    public TestClass deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        //do some login
        return test;
    }

}
```

When I submit the form and post `test` inside model to the controller, `deserialize` method called, but it gives me the following exception:

```
Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "field1" (class ***.***.MyModel), not marked as ignorable
```

How can I solve this problem?

Also I used `@JsonProperty` on top of `TestClass` in the model, but problem not solved.

Comment: It says class `MyModel`, not `TestClass`.